# Array.filter is returning empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, object, filtering

I am trying to get the failure Details based on Date.
For this I am applying array.filter but it is returning empty array.

Below is my array:

```
value:[{
  "Date": "02/04/2019",
  "Total": "1000",
  "Success": "850",
  "Failure": "150",
  "FailureDeatils": [{
      "Reason": "Reason1",
      "Count": 2
    },
    {
      "Reason": "Reason2",
      "Count": 6
    }
  ]
}, {
  "Date": "03/04/2019",
  "Total": "800",
  "Success": "750",
  "Failure": "150",
  "FailureDeatils": [{
    "Reason": "Reason1",
    "Count": 3
  }, {
    "Reason": "Reason2",
    "Count": 1
  }]
}]
```

And if I give the date as 02/04/2019,it should return the following:

```
{
  "FailureDeatils": [{
      "Reason": "Reason1",
      "Count": 2
    },
    {
      "Reason": "Reason2",
      "Count": 6
    }
  ]
}
```

I am using below array.filter method:

```
var filtered = value.filter(isPresent);
function isPresent(value) {
  return value == 02/04/2019;
}
```

this is returning empty array.

Can anyone please figure me out where I am going wrong?

Comment: `return value.Date == "02/04/2019";` maybe?

Comment: What is isPresent? please share the condition you're applying using isPresent

Comment: is Present is nothing but the function written below

Comment: Alright, I've added an answer based on your code. You can test it on browser console as well before implementing in your code.

Comment: Please upvote the question if it worked for you. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working code based on your Array.

```
var value = [{
  "Date": "02/04/2019",
  "Total": "1000",
  "Success": "850",
  "Failure": "150",
  "FailureDeatils": [{
      "Reason": "Reason1",
      "Count": 2
    },
    {
      "Reason": "Reason2",
      "Count": 6
    }
  ]
}, {
  "Date": "03/04/2019",
  "Total": "800",
  "Success": "750",
  "Failure": "150",
  "FailureDeatils": [{
    "Reason": "Reason1",
    "Count": 3
  }, {
    "Reason": "Reason2",
    "Count": 1
  }]
}];

var filtered = value.filter (isPresent).map (obj => obj.FailureDeatils);;
function isPresent (value) {
  return value.Date == "02/04/2019";
}

console.log (filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your function `isPresent`, `value` is each object in the array

And you're compaing the entire object to a value

What you need to do is compare the object property of that object

```js
function isPresent(value) {
    return value.Date == "02/04/2019";
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! I can get the entire data now but I need only Failure Details out of that

Answer (score 1):

You need to check over `value.Date` and not `value` because `value` or the callback param will hold the whole iterated `object` from your `array`:

```
function isPresent(value) {
  return value.Date && value.Date == "02/04/2019";
}
```

To get only `FailureDeatils` from your filtered `object`, you can map
   the filtered result with **[`Array#map()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**:

```
var filtered = data.filter(isPresent).map(o => { return {"FailureDeatils": o.FailureDeatils}});
```

**Note:**

- Make sure to wrap `"02/04/2019"` between `""` so it can be evaluated as `string` and correctly compared, otherwise it will be calculated and treated as `Number` and gives wrong filtering results.
- Avoid using the same variable name `value` twice for your array and
  for the callback parameter for better readability of your code.

**Demo:**

```js
var data = [{
  "Date": "02/04/2019",
  "Total": "1000",
  "Success": "850",
  "Failure": "150",
  "FailureDeatils": [{
      "Reason": "Reason1",
      "Count": 2
    },
    {
      "Reason": "Reason2",
      "Count": 6
    }
  ]
}, {
  "Date": "03/04/2019",
  "Total": "800",
  "Success": "750",
  "Failure": "150",
  "FailureDeatils": [{
    "Reason": "Reason1",
    "Count": 3
  }, {
    "Reason": "Reason2",
    "Count": 1
  }]
}]



var filtered = data.filter(isPresent).map(e => { return {"FailureDeatils": e.FailureDeatils}});

function isPresent(value) {
  return value.Date && value.Date == "02/04/2019";
}

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var filtered = value.filter(function(a){
                   return a.Date === "02/04/2019";
               });
```

Comment: `02/04/2019` will be calculated here, see result of `console.log(02/04/2019)`

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this -

```
const value = [{
  "Date": "02/04/2019",
  "Total": "1000",
  "Success": "850",
  "Failure": "150",
  "FailureDeatils": [{
      "Reason": "Reason1",
      "Count": 2
    },
    {
      "Reason": "Reason2",
      "Count": 6
    }
  ]
}, {
  "Date": "03/04/2019",
  "Total": "800",
  "Success": "750",
  "Failure": "150",
  "FailureDeatils": [{
    "Reason": "Reason1",
    "Count": 3
  }, {
    "Reason": "Reason2",
    "Count": 1
  }]
}]

const filtered = value.filter((x) => x.Date === "02/04/2019");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const value = [{
      "Date": "02/04/2019",
      "Total": "1000",
      "Success": "850",
      "Failure": "150",
      "FailureDeatils": [{
          "Reason": "Reason1",
          "Count": 2
        },
        {
          "Reason": "Reason2",
          "Count": 6
        }
      ]
    }, {
      "Date": "03/04/2019",
      "Total": "800",
      "Success": "750",
      "Failure": "150",
      "FailureDeatils": [{
        "Reason": "Reason1",
        "Count": 3
      }, {
        "Reason": "Reason2",
        "Count": 1
      }]
    }]   

    var filtered = value.filter(isPresent).map(row => {
      return {
        FailureDeatils : row.FailureDeatils
      }
    });
    function isPresent(value) {
      return value.Date === "02/04/2019";
    }

    console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
const value = [{"Date": "02/04/2019","Total": "1000","Success": "850","Failure": "150","FailureDeatils":[{"Reason":"Reason1","Count":2}, {"Reason":"Reason2","Count":6}]},{"Date": "03/04/2019","Total": "800","Success": "750","Failure": "150","FailureDeatils": [{"Reason":"Reason1","Count":3},{"Reason":"Reason2","Count":1}]}];
const isPresent = ({Date}) => Date === '02/04/2019';
const filtered = value.filter(isPresent);

console.log(filtered);
```